# Contrapositive negation quanitifier

Tags: logic, proof-writing

> Find the contrapositive of : For all $x\in R$, if $x^6+ 3x^4 - 3x <0$, then $0< x <1.$

Is the contrapositive: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} x^6+3x^4-3x<0$   and $((x\leq 0) or (x\geq 1))$

I am mainly confused about the quantifier.

Comment: $\forall x \in \mathbb R,$ If $$\big((x\leq 0 \lor x \geq 1)\rightarrow (x^6 + 3x^4 - 3x \geq 0)\big)$$

Answer (score 2):

> Find the contrapositive of : For all $x\in \mathbb R$, if $x^6+ 3x^4 - 3x <0$, then $0< x <1.$

**Contrapositive:** $$\forall x \in \mathbb R,\big((x\leq 0 \lor x \geq 1)\rightarrow (x^6 + 3x^4 - 3x \geq 0)\big)$$

Don't confuse the **negation** of a quantified statement with the  contrapositive of an implication. The **negation** of $\forall x\in \mathbb R, \;\;\Big((x^6 + 3x^4 - 3 \gt 0) \rightarrow (0\lt x\lt 1)\big)$ is $$\exists x \in \mathbb R \;\;\lnot\Big((x^6 + 3x^4 - 3 \gt 0) \rightarrow (0\lt x \lt 1)\Big)\\ \equiv \exists x \in \mathbb R \;\;\Big( (x^6 + 3x^4 - 3\gt 0) \land (x\leq 0 \lor x\geq 1)\Big)$$